# HIbernate mapping join student-grade

Tags: hibernate, join, annotations

This is a really simple question, but I cannot get this mapping to work in hibernate.

I have 2 tables

```
Student
-Student Id
-Biology Grade Id

Biology Grades
- Grade Id
- Grade Name (e.g. A,B, C, D)
```

Each student has just one biology grade, but many students may get the same biology grade.

Is this a @OneToOne join or @OneToMany? I am using java classes with hibernate annotations. I need to Cascade, but do not want duplicate entries in the Grades column. How would I do this?

Comment: What do *you* think it is and why? How many grades can a student have? How many students can have the same grade?

Comment: So you answered the question: It's a ManyToOne: Many students have One grade. Now try to map it, post what you tried, and tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: So I don't want the grade object to hold a list of students. I just want each student to be mapped to a biology grade. (I have to iterate over students and set it a grade). Is it a OneToOne that I need? I tried that, with a cascade, then I got primary key violations as I started adding students. (The grades were being added multiple times)

Comment: What is unclear in *"It's a ManyToOne"*. Given that comment, what makes you think it's a OneToOne that you need? You shouldn't have any cascading.

Comment: I don't want the biology grade to store a list of students.

Comment: So what? It's still a ManyToOne. A unidirectional ManyToOne.

Comment: I need the relationship to on the student side.

Comment: So define it there, as a unidirectional ManyToOne association. What's the problem? If you're so stuck and don't understand how to define a ManyToOne association, have you considered... reading the documentation? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one